# Get all elements with specific prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototype

Let's take this example:

```
var Point = new function(){};

var Line = function(){};
    Line.prototype = new Point();

var line2 ....
```

I wan't to find all the entities that prototype Point. Some code I attempted but its not working:

```
for(key in window) {
  if(this[key] == Point){ // typeof is also not working.
     console.log(this[key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: `Line.prototype = new Point();` ? Do you mean find any property that instantiates a `Point()`

Comment: @adeneo Yes, that what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change `==` in your example to `instanceof`, it will work for all global variables that have a `Point` object as their prototype:

```
for(key in window) {
  if(this[key] instanceof Point){ // <== using instanceof here
     console.log(this[key]);
  }
}
```

But you have an error in your definition of `Point`. You don't want `new` there, because later you use `Point` as a function. But `new function() { }` **calls** that anonymous function as a constructor and returns the non-function object created by `new`.

Complete working example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/usozap/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/usozap/1/edit)

```
var Point = function(){};

var Line = function(){};
    Line.prototype = new Point();

var lineInstance = new Line();
var pointInstance = new Point();

for(key in window) {
  if(window[key] instanceof Point){
     console.log(key + " is 'instanceof' Point");
  }
}
```

Notes on the above:

- No `new` on the first line.
- I actually create objects using `new Point` and `new Line`.
- I've used `window` in both places in the loop. Using `window` in one place but `this` in another is just confusing (even though, in this case, they both refer to the same object).

---

If your goal is to find functions (line `Line`) that use a `Point` object as their `prototype` property (note that that property is **not** the prototype of any object, but it will *become* the prototype of objects created via those functions via `new`), then look at the `prototype` property: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/usozap/2) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/usozap/2/edit)

```
for(key in window) {
  if(typeof window[key] === "function" &&
     window[key].prototype instanceof Point){
     console.log(key + " is a function using Point as its prototype property");
  }
}
```

---

I think the problem here may be that you're mistaking the concept of an object's prototype and the `prototype` property of functions, which are different but related things:

- The `prototype` property of a function is just that: A property of the function.
- When you create an **object** by calling a function via `new` (e.g., using it as a constructor function), one of the things that happens during the call using `new` is that a new object is created and is assigned its underlying prototype (which is not accessible as any property on the object*) from the constructor function's `prototype` property.

This is best explained with an example:

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype.bar = 42;

var f = new Foo();
console.log(f.bar); // "42"
```

The `Foo` function has a property called `prototype`. When we create a new object via `new Foo`, it gets its underlying prototype from `Foo.prototype` and so if we look up a property on that object and it doesn't have its own copy, the JavaScript engine looks at the prototype to see if *it* has one. And so the last line above works, logging `"42"` to the console.

(* I say above that the prototype underlying an object is not accessible as any property on the object. And that's true of JavaScript according to the standard. However, there is a *non-standard* extension that many engines provide, a property called `__proto__`, which is exactly that: The object's underlying prototype. But that's not standard. Within the standard, you can get an object's prototype by passing the object into `Object.getPrototypeOf`, which is new as of ES5.)

---

And finally: It is presumably just a throw-away example, but I wouldn't normally expect `Line` to inherit from `Point`, because there is no "is a" relationship (a `Line` is not a `Point`). The usual relationship here would be *composition*, not inheritance. A `Line` *has* `Point`s, but a `Line` isn't a `Point`.

Comment: @Jessica: That's because of the incorrect `new` on your definition of `Point`. See the updated answer and example.

Comment: @Jessica: Your fiddle doesn't create any objects using `Point` as their prototype. It only creates functions that use `Point` as their `prototype` property, which is something completely different.

Comment: So with out an Instance Object i can't check for prototype of Point?

Comment: @Jessica: Just like without a car, you can't kick a car's tires.

Comment: Its makes scene now, Can you maybe remomed some resource(s)  to better understand this type of area? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All elements will have different prototypes, because every element's prototype is a different instance of Point.

If you use the same prototype for them all, then you can compare. Otherwise, do as T.J. Crowder said and use `instanceof`.